# Why does the docker registry not show a UI?

Tags: dockerhub

According to [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) it is possible to start a private docker hub by executing:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always registry:2
```

Perhaps something was wrong with the build, so the following was tried as well:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always registry:latest
```

but the problem persists.

The problem is that navigating to localhost:5000 returns a blank page instead of the UI.

I have reported an [issue](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/2124) on Github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [joaofnfernandes commented 9 hours ago](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/2124)
>
> Docker Registry is a backend service and doesn't have any web UI.
>
> You can continue learning about Docker Registry here. If you're
>   looking for a registry with a management UI, maybe take a look into
>   Docker Trusted Registry.
>
> I'm closing this issue since it doesn't report anything we can improve
>   on docs.docker.com. Feel free to open more issues if you find anything
>   wrong with docs.docker.com

Answer (score 1):

Docker registry is a background service without UI, they wont be doing something like UI in a short time-span as it isn't their main focus.

If you would like a UI for your Docker registry, then you could use a container containing [a full UI](https://hub.docker.com/r/joxit/docker-registry-ui/).

Demo by running: `docker run -d -p 80:80 joxit/docker-registry-ui`